# Automatically kill the IIS 7 process which is hanging

Tags: iis-7, iis

I have an intermittently occurring problem with my application.  It is always under relatively high load (10-50 req/second).  Most of the time it runs fantastic, with CPU < 10%.  Occasionally (about once per week) it will suddenly ramp up to 100% CPU over the course of about 3 minutes and then stay there causing the server to become unresponsive until I kill the w3wp.exe.  I'm continuing to try to debug this problem.  In the mean time I need a temporary solution.

Is there a service or tool I can use to monitor the w3wp.exe and automatically kill the process if it goes above 80% utilization for a period of time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS can take care of this by itself; you can configure an application pool to be recycled (i.e. restarted) when its CPU usage stays above a certain threshold for a given period of time.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to give that a try.  For the record this setting can be found under Application Pools -> Select Pool -> Advanced -> CPU.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have other machines in your environment, but I'd suggest putting some monitoring in.  Nagios or Zabbix or an application like that.  They can monitor cpu / disk space / memory usage/ etc etc... if your cpu usage stays over 80% or 90% for whatever amount of time you deem too long you could then have that monitoring system fire off a job (zabbix is able to do this, call external items) to kill that pool.  With this solution there is a bit of a learning curve however, you would need to learn the application and to write a script to do the app pool restart... something like a .net app or a vb script that uses IIS app to determine the application pool responsible and then a command line kill on that process.